How to modify Arviz.Plot.Trace?
With these small lines:
with model:
    az.plot_trace(data=idata, kind="trace", legend=True, figsize=(6, 3))
    plt.suptitle("Model Trace", fontsize=20)

I can modify a bit (general title and size) the trace plot as shown below:

I am quite sure it's also possible to modify the variable name mu (for example increase size or change the font), but I don't see why ?
I am also quite sure it's possible to change the plot frame by setting the two plots vertically ?
I suspect some kwargs are involved in the many parameters of the arviz.plot_trace function, but I am unsure in how to properly use these additional parameters.
Do you have some example of using plot_kwargs, fill_kwargs , trace_kwargs, or others ?
Thanks for any hint on the subject.
